# An error using internationalization in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm learning internationalization. And have example with classes`ResourceBundle` и `ListResourceBundle`.

The example demonstrates the use of resource bundles SampleRB.
After compilation, I'm constantly getting an error:

```
Английская версия программы: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.ListResourceBundle.loadLookup(ListResourceBundle.java:202)
    at java.util.ListResourceBundle.handleGetObject(ListResourceBundle.java:130)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getObject(ResourceBundle.java:441)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getString(ResourceBundle.java:407)
    at LRBDemo.LRBDemo.main(LRBDemo.java:12)
```

The program consists of the class **LRBDemo** with the main method:

```
public class LRBDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ResourceBundle rd = ResourceBundle.getBundle("LRBDemo.SampleRB");

        System.out.println("Английская версия программы: ");
        System.out.println("Строка по ключу Title: " + rd.getString("title"));
        System.out.println("Строка по ключу StopText: " + rd.getString("StopText"));
        System.out.println("Строка по ключу StartText: " + rd.getString("StartText"));


        rd = ResourceBundle.getBundle("LRBDemo.SampleRBde", Locale.GERMAN);

        System.out.println("\nНемецкая версия программы: ");
        System.out.println("Строка для ключа Title: " + rd.getString("title"));
        System.out.println("Строка по ключу StopText: " + rd.getString("StopText"));
        System.out.println("Строка по ключу StartText: " + rd.getString("StartText"));
    }
}
```

Class **SampleRB** using English language:

```
public class SampleRB extends ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents() {
        Object[][]  resources = new Object[3][2];

        resources[0][0] = "title";
        resources[0][1] = "MyProgram";

        resources[1][0] = "StopText";
        resources[1][1] = "Stop";

        resources[1][0] = "StartText";
        resources[2][1] = "Start";

        return resources;
    }
}
```

And class **SampleRBde** using German language:

```
public class SampleRBde extends ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents() {
        Object[][] resources = new Object[3][2];

        resources[0][0] = "title";
        resources[0][1] = "Mein Programm";

        resources[1][0] = "StopText";
        resources[1][1] = "Anschlag";

        resources[2][0] = "StartText";
        resources[2][1] = "Anfang";

        return resources;
    }
}
```

If I'm writing in class **LRBDemo** instead of `ResourceBundle rd = ResourceBundle.getBundle("LRBDemo.SampleRB")` this snippet `ResourceBundle rd = ResourceBundle.getBundle("SampleRB")` and `rd = ResourceBundle.getBundle("LRBDemo.SampleRBde", Locale.GERMAN);` like `rd = ResourceBundle.getBundle("SampleRBde", Locale.GERMAN);`(means without package), then getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name SampleRB, locale ru_RU
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1564)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1387)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:773)
    at LRBDemo.LRBDemo.main(LRBDemo.java:9)
```

The structure of my project:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Any answer will be appreciated <3

**UPD:**

1)

```
 public class LRBDemo {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // загрузить комплект ресурсов по умолчанию
            ResourceBundle rd = ResourceBundle.getBundle("LRBDemo.SampleRB");

            System.out.println("Английская версия программы: ");
            System.out.println("Строка по ключу Title: " + rd.getString("title"));
            System.out.println("Строка по ключу StopText: " + rd.getString("StopText"));
            System.out.println("Строка по ключу StartText: " + rd.getString("StartText"));

            // загрузить комплект ресурсов для поддержки немецкого языка
            rd = ResourceBundle.getBundle("LRBDemo.SampleRBde", Locale.GERMAN);

            System.out.println("\nНемецкая версия программы: ");
            System.out.println("Строка для ключа Title: " + rd.getString("title"));
            System.out.println("Строка по ключу StopText: " + rd.getString("StopText"));
            System.out.println("Строка по ключу StartText: " + rd.getString("StartText"));
        }
    }
```

2)

```
public class LRBDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // загрузить комплект ресурсов по умолчанию
        ResourceBundle rd = ResourceBundle.getBundle(SampleRB.class.getName());

        System.out.println("Английская версия программы: ");
        System.out.println("Строка по ключу Title: " + rd.getString("title"));
        System.out.println("Строка по ключу StopText: " + rd.getString("StopText"));
        System.out.println("Строка по ключу StartText: " + rd.getString("StartText"));

        // загрузить комплект ресурсов для поддержки немецкого языка
        rd = ResourceBundle.getBundle(SampleRBde.class.getName());

        System.out.println("\nНемецкая версия программы: ");
        System.out.println("Строка для ключа Title: " + rd.getString("title"));
        System.out.println("Строка по ключу StopText: " + rd.getString("StopText"));
        System.out.println("Строка по ключу StartText: " + rd.getString("StartText"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple typo: `resources[1][0] = "StartText";` should be `resources[2][0] = "StartText";`. Since you weren't setting `resources[2][0]`, an NPE resulted when it tried to use it.

As for the "Can't find bundle" error, the class name you give to getBundle needs to be fully qualified with its package. If you don't want to type the package name, you can use `SampleRB.class.getName()` instead of `"LRBDemo.SampleRB"`.

Comment: Thanks, Joseph. Do you know how to solve the problem:  "Can't find bundle for base name SampleRB, locale ru_RU"?

Comment: Yep. Edited in.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class SampleRB extends ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents() {
        Object[][]  resources = new Object[3][2];

        ...

        resources[2][0] = "StartText"; //change this line.
        resources[2][1] = "Start";

        return resources;
    }
}
```

You mistyped the indices in the class. This would fix the error in `SampleRB`.